# Enum with Hex value basic arithmetic

Tags: c#, enums, hex

Say we have an enum as:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
     None = 0x0000,
     Value1 = 0x0001,        
     Value2 = 0x0002,
     Value3 = 0x0200
     Defautl = Value1 | Value2
     SomeOtherDefault = Value1 | Value3
}
```

So in such a case, for a given SomeEnum type value, how can we check if Value2 is present and then toggle it (set if not-set or viceversa)?
Given value could be as:

```
tempValue = Value1 | Value3 | Value2
```

It must be a simple thing, but I am not used to hex values in enums.

Comment: @Soner I didn't get the point of your edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle it:

```
myValue ^= Value2;
```

To check if it has it:

```
if (myValue & Value2 != 0)
```

Comment: Don't test whether it's positive.  For these flags it doesn't matter, but in general it's possible for flags to have the sign bit set.

Comment: @BenVoigt True, fixed.

Comment: Thanks ^ is the operator I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = tempValue & Value2;
if (value != 0)
{
    // Value2 is set
}
```

To toggle

```
tempValue = tempValue ^ Value2;
```

Or as the answer below has it

```
tempValue ^= Value2;
```

Comment: You don't even need to cast it. He also asked for a way on how to toggle it too, you know.

Comment: You do need to cast it if you're storing in an `int` variable.  Why are you doing that?